# Java private nested classes

Tags: java, inner-classes

Consider the following example:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Invoice {

    private static class Item {
        String description;
        int quantity;
        double unitPrice;

        double price() { return quantity * unitPrice; }
    }

    private ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addItem(String description, int quantity, 
                        double unitPrice) {
        Item newItem = new Item();
        newItem.description = description;
        newItem.quantity = quantity;
        newItem.unitPrice = unitPrice;
        items.add(newItem);
    }

}
```

I understand that the nested class is only visible to the enclosing outer class. However I have following question.

Why are we allowed to directly access an instance variable of the inner class `newItem.description`? Is this because the default visibility modifier is public in this class for the instance field? Usually we would have a series of setter and getter methods.

Furthermore, I tried making one of the instance variables of the nested class private (`private int quantity`) yet the compiler still did not complain.

Comment: What's your question? Why shouldn't they be accessible?

Comment: One of main reasons nested classes exist, is to let direct access of its members (including private ones) to outer class(es) and vice-versa.

Comment: There is no inner class here, only a nested static class.